# I am not able to create VF Page?

Tags: visualforce

Please help me to Create a VF Page using dashboard.?

how to use dashboard Components to create VF page?

Comment: You can't create a VF page using dashboard components, you need to goto Setup -> Develop -> Visualforce Pages -> "New"

Comment: i want to create  a VF Page using dashboard Components (is there any code

Comment: You can't create a vf page using dashboard components. If you mean create a vf pages that includes dashboard components then there are lots of examples via a Google search. This forum is not the proper place to ask for samples.

Comment: Ok.. you have any proper link to understand clearly

Comment: thank you sir....i have one question in my mind that .... how i create dashboards on my all accounts with revenue wise.

Comment: with revenue wise i want to create all accounts name wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that maybe you want to create dashboard components using visual force pagers. If that is the case you can search and find many examples. 
You can start with something like this: [Visualforce Dashboard Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Viasur! Can you post some of the relevant content from that link? Links tend to break over time making answers without details a bit useless in the long term :)